# Standard solution to run list of scripts as a cron job (fluentd maybe?)

Tags: scripting, devops, prometheus, cron-task, fluentd

I need to run regularly several scripts and resend their output in a format of Prometheus metrics.

For the moment I use home-made solution on Flask with a background cron job, dump output into files, parse them and convert into .prom format, and then expose via NodeExporter.. bref.

That seems to be overkill and home-made for nothing.
I wonder if there is a standard solution, which could run scripts, parse their output and expose at /metrics or resend in Prometheus or Fluentd format?

Could Fluentd be suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to execute your script, you could:

1. Start a fluentd instance with proper `fluentd.config`
2. Run your script and send the output to the running fluentd
3. `fluentd.config` should be configured to point to your prometheus

If you're using `Kubernetes` you could think to a pod with 2 containers (fluentd + your custom container with script). You also may schedule it with a `CronJob`.

You should take a look at those links:

- https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/monitoring-prometheus
- https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-prometheus

Comment: You didn't get my point - I look for CronJob replacement. I have really a lot of scripts, hundreds of them. And I expect that smth will run all these scripts for me, and collect and parse their output.

Comment: It was not clear where these scripts are run. On a node (from the OS)? Or from inside K8S? You didn't mention Kubernetes.